# Why does 'composing' Series not result in the 'input' Series's index?

Tags: python, pandas

I would expect that indexing one Series by another would result in a new Series whose index is the same as the indexing Series. However it is instead a combination of the index of the indexed and the indexing Series.

Running

```py
A = pandas.Series(range(3), index=list("ABC"))
B = pandas.Series(list("AABBCC"), index=list("XYZWVU"))

print(A[B])
```

yields

```py
A    0
A    0
B    1
B    1
C    2
C    2
dtype: int64
```

So the index here has the shape of `B.index` but the values of `A.index`.

I would instead have expected that the index for `A[B]` would be identical to `B.index`, as if composing two mappings. Why is it not like this? Is there a use to the current setup (which seems to me to be useless)? Is there a 'correct' way to get what I'm looking for?

This problem makes certain operations tricky. For example,

```py
B[A[B] == 2]
```

would intuitively be how to select the entries of B whose values yield 2 when looking them up in A. (This is useful if B is a DataFrame with some object IDs in one column and we want to select rows of B based off a value of that object stored in a secondary table.) However this yields an `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` exception. This works if you drop the index:

```py
B[(A[B] == 2).values]
```

Is using `.values` the proper way to do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, indexing is choosing the corresponding indexes. So really `A[B]` should still have `index` in `A.index`.

If instead, you want to map the values, then use `map`. And it seems faster too:

```
%timeit -n 1000 B.map(A)
# 196 µs ± 6.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 A[B]
# 384 µs ± 5.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And:

```
%timeit -n 1000 B[B.map(A).eq(2)]
# 624 µs ± 38.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 B[A[B].eq(2).values]
#779 µs ± 7.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```